# How to draw an outlined path on android canvas

Tags: android, path, drawing, android-canvas

Is there a good way of drawing a path (or even just a straight line) on an android canvas where the line is in one color, but outlined with another? Here's what I'm looking to draw:

[image: Outlined Path]

...the purpose of course being that the line (in my case a dashed line) is easily visible on both a black and white background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first draw a thicker line with the color of the border, over it, you draw another line, at a distance of 1px to every side of the other line, so it will cover the first line, but 1 keeping visible 1px around the second line. something like this:

```
  public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;//remenber to inicialize them with actual values
            int  BORDER_COLOR, INNER_COLOR;//remenber to inicialize them with actual values

            Paint paint = new Paint();

            paint.setColor( BORDER_COLOR);
            canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, stopX, stopY, paint);

            paint.setColor( INNER_COLOR);
            canvas.drawLine(startX+1, startY+1, stopX-1, stopY-1, paint);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks -- I don't know why I didn't think of this! of course, I'll have to give a little thought to the spacing of the dashes, but it's probably the same general principle.

Comment: Sure, you will have to think, and try a few. Keep in mind also different devices densities. You will want to retrieve device density, and compute the spacing and the stroke width depending on the density, so it look the same in every phone.

Answer (score 1):

draw twice: with different color and different stroke width